# magit blame: is there an equivalent for "show me the file before this commit" from VC?

Tags: magit

VC blame mode has a nifty `a` hotkey "show me blame of the file before the commit I'm pointing at".

Is there an equivalent in magit?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, just invoke `magit-blame` again. You can do so using <kbd>b b</kbd>. To move back in the other direction use <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: This is an amazing feature which lets you explore git history in a very cool way. I wish the [magit manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Blaming.html) was more clear on how to use it so more people knew about it.